# Make JS wait until wikipedia API redirects before displaying contents

Tags: javascript, html, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am embedding Wikipedia articles into my website using the following code.

- It works correctly if I insert a phase that comes directly from a page's URL as the `wiki_links_extract`.
- It does not work correctly if I insert a phrase from a page that *then redirects to* the page of interest. Instead of returning the page contents, it returns the words **"Redirects to"**

Eg.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B._21 -- `B._21` does not work

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_and_Charcoal_Burner -- `King_and_Charcoal_Burner` works.

Can I modify my script to wait until the redirecting is completed, and then returns the final page?

```
  var url_start =
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=";

  var url_middle = wiki_link_extract;

  var url_end = "&callback=?";

  var full_url = url_start + url_middle + url_end;

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: full_url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
      var blurb = $("<div></div>").html(markup);
      $(".article-content-main").html($(blurb).find("p"));
    },
    error: function (errorMessage) {},
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs here https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse you can see a query parameter `redirects`

You need to do `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&redirects&page=B._21`

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for, thank you